# How to install wine with .NET framework instead of mono?

Tags: fedora, wine, mono, .net

I am using fedora 23 and I want to install .NET framework 4 in wine.

based on [here](http://wiki.winehq.org/Mono), I have to remove mono first. But when I run the following command I receive unsuccessful result.

```
$ wine uninstaller --remove '{E45D8920-A758-4088-B6C6-31DBB276992E}'
fixme:ntdll:find_reg_tz_info Can't find matching timezone information in the registry for bias -210, std (d/m/y): 22/09/2015, dlt (d/m/y): 22/03/2015
fixme:winediag:start_process Wine Staging 1.7.55 is a testing version containing experimental patches.
fixme:winediag:start_process Please mention your exact version when filing bug reports on winehq.org.
fixme:ntdll:find_reg_tz_info Can't find matching timezone information in the registry for bias -210, std (d/m/y): 22/09/2015, dlt (d/m/y): 22/03/2015
fixme:ntdll:find_reg_tz_info Can't find matching timezone information in the registry for bias -210, std (d/m/y): 22/09/2015, dlt (d/m/y): 22/03/2015
fixme:ntdll:find_reg_tz_info Can't find matching timezone information in the registry for bias -210, std (d/m/y): 22/09/2015, dlt (d/m/y): 22/03/2015
fixme:ntdll:find_reg_tz_info Can't find matching timezone information in the registry for bias -210, std (d/m/y): 22/09/2015, dlt (d/m/y): 22/03/2015
fixme:ntdll:find_reg_tz_info Can't find matching timezone information in the registry for bias -210, std (d/m/y): 22/09/2015, dlt (d/m/y): 22/03/2015
fixme:ntdll:find_reg_tz_info Can't find matching timezone information in the registry for bias -210, std (d/m/y): 22/09/2015, dlt (d/m/y): 22/03/2015
uninstaller: The application with GUID '{E45D8920-A758-4088-B6C6-31DBB276992E}' was not found
```

Removing **wine-mono** package removes main **wine** packages too.

Please tell me how can I remove mono?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to install .NET 4.0 is to use the newest [Winetricks](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks) script:

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
$ sh winetricks dotnet40
```

Also, **if you have 64-bit wine** installed, you will **need to use newer .NET 4.5** (`dotnet45`) instead of 4.0.

Comment: it is only possible to change the architecture to **32-bit** using this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/177192/how-do-i-create-a-32-bit-wine-prefix)